# Tensorflow Fails to load when running Python program through a bash script

Tags: python, bash, tensorflow, keras

I've been using Keras with the TensorFlow/CUDA backend without any problems on macOS Sierra in the Jupyter Notebooks and by running my Python code directly.

However, I've noticed that if I try to run my Python programs via a bash script, TensorFlow fails to load:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import activations
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/activations.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import backend as K
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 73, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so, 10): Library not loaded: @rpath/libcublas.8.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so
  Reason: image not found

Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
```

I don't understand why this error is happening, I've set the right environmental variables in my .bash_profile file:

```
export CUDA_HOME=/usr/local/cuda
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:$CUDA_HOME/lib"
export PATH="$CUDA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Comment: Can you try adding those `export` statements to your Bash script and see if that makes it work? (I suspect the problem is whatever environment your script inherits, but I'm not sure how you're running it....)

Comment: Thanks for the message, I gave it a go and it warned me about unbound variables. The thing I find strange is how its almost like Bash isn't aware of some TensorFlow internal path variables.

Comment: That's strange... perhaps you could try running `export` (with no argument) in the script to see the whole set of environment variables? As far as I can see the only free variable in your `export` statements is `$PATH`, which *surely must be* bound in your script!